# passing $this as collection to $self in php not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following code bellow and it works in `JavaScript`
but its not working on `PHP`

**JS**

```
code2: function () {
   var self = this
   sample.map(function(){
     self // work fine here
   });
}
```

**PHP**

```
public function sample () {
  $self = $this;
  array_map(function(){
    $self; // undefined variable here
  }, $sampleArray);
}
```

Comment: This is a problem of scope - look into `function() use() {...}`

Answer (score 3):

If you use closures in **Javascript**, all variables visible in the parent scope are visible in the scope. It's not the case with **PHP**, where you need to explicitly state which variables should be visible. You do that with the **use()** statement.

The following should do the trick:

```
array_map(function() use ($self) {
    $self; // this will now be defined
  }, $sampleArray);
```